# Changes buttons value with the same ID

Tags: javascript, php

When I have this it works fine.

```
//php
<input id="somename" type="button" value="Text1" />

//script
<script>
  document.getElementById('somename').onclick = function(){
    this.value = this.value === 'Text1' ? 'Text2' : 'Text1';
  }
</script>
```

But when I have this it works only for the first button.

```
//php

<input id="somename" type="button" value="Text1" />
<input id="somename" type="button" value="Text1" />

//Script
<script>
  document.getElementById('somename').onclick = function(){
    this.value = this.value === 'Text1' ? 'Text2' : 'Text1';
  }
</script>
```

Is there any way to work for any number of buttons? I would like to use the same id and value for all buttons.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: classes accomplish exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have only **one** element with an specific *id*. Use the *name* or *class* HTML attribute instead. Therefore you could get an array of elements by executing *document.getElementsByClassName* or *getElementsByName*.

Try this, using just pure javascript

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByName('somename'), function(button){
    button.onclick = function(){
        this.value = this.value === 'Text1' ? 'Text2' : 'Text1';
    };
});
```

And in your HTML remember to change the *id* attributes for *name* attributes:

```
<input name="somename" type="button" value="Text1" />
<input name="somename" type="button" value="Text1" />
```

I've made this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmo3xp1d/) for you to see the code working. Check it out!

Comment: That won't (and can't) work, without changes to the HTML. Which you might want to explain...

Answer (score 2):

You should use a class, not an id. You can use JQuery to set listeners and change the values for all elements of your somename class:

```
<input class="somename" type="button" value="Text1" />
<input class="somename" type="button" value="Text1" />

<script>
  $('.somename').click(function(){$(this).val(this.value === 'Text1' ? 'Text2' : 'Text1')});
</script>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lk6nfn2c/1/

Comment: Why do you imply that jQuery is required?

Comment: It's not, and I upvoted @raina77ow's answer as a way to do so using pure JS. However, JQuery does make the code somewhat easier.

Comment: This changes all buttons value when I press one.

Comment: Yes; I misinterpreted the desired behavior. If you only want to change a single button's value, use $(this).val(...) instead of $('.somename').val(...)

Comment: Or just `this.value = this.value...`. It's not necessary to go all jQuery. ) Still +1 from me for showing the difference jQuery makes - one doesn't have to worry about cross-platform compatibility and IE event quirks.

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead of id then iterate over them

```
//php

<input class="somename" type="button" value="Text1" />
<input class="somename" type="button" value="Text1" />

//Script
<script>
   var someNamesElm = document.getElementsByClass('somename');
   var someNamesElmNbr = someNamesElm.length;
   for (var i = 0; i < someNamesElmNbr; i++) {
     someNamesElm[i].onclick = function(){
        this.value = this.value === 'Text1' ? 'Text2' : 'Text1';
     }        
  }
</script>
```